# Cant get drop shadow as per PNG image in C# background image of form

Tags: c#

I've form in .net C#,

**Problem:**

I've a PNG image with drop shadow and I want put that image as back ground image of form and also using  transparency key as well with the same background color property. But when I debug my app it does not give expected drop shadow as per png image. Please help me.

Comment: Could you please provide some code for what you did so far?

Comment: We would love to help you, but it's hard when you don't provide the code(that doesn't work as you wish). (I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Winforms, right? __It will not work__. Drop shadows have semi-tranparent pixels and the tranparency key will only work all or nothing. So you will always get ugly mismatching pixels unless your background happens to be right. I guess you will need WPF to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @taw i think winform is bad for design it is full with the bugs we can only code not design like WPF..

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to programmatically adjust the transparency of the image.

Background images on a form do not support any photo attributes/editing, just set or get. So you'll need to get your photo and the background color of the form, and then programmatically change the photo to look as if it is transparent to the background color of the image.

Then take the image and set it as the background image of the form.

But without more information, I'm not sure what else to say or if I've said the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution.
ModernUI Theme for .Net WinForms supports two kinds of Shadow Effects. See 
 image below.

[WinForm ModernUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHmFo.jpg)

It's under MIT on GitHub:
https://github.com/NetDimension/WinForm-ModernUI